# Coding : Can anyone explain me this why there are different outputs when comparing Least significant bits of two numbers?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Can anyone explain me this why there are different outputs when comparing Least significant bits of two numbers?
In 1st case I comparing them directly
In second case I assigned LSB to other variables

```
        //Program to check Least significant bits of two numbers 
        #include<stdio.h>
            int main(){

                //LSB means least significant bit of the binary number
                //(i.e.,Unit place digit in binary number) 
                //Example..... 2 = 10(in binary) and 9 = 1001(in binary)  
                //so least significant bit is 0 for 2 and 1 for 9

               //In binary M =101 and LSB of M = 1 
               int M = 5; 
               //In binary P = 011 and LSB of P  = 1
               int P = 3;

               //printing LSB values
               printf("\nLeast significant bits are for M : %d and for P : %d",M&1,P&1);

               //Comparing LSB of M and LSB of P
               if(M&1 != P&1) { 
                   printf("\nLeast significant bits are not equal"); 
               }
               else printf("\nLeast significant bits are equal"); 

               //Assigning Least significant bit of M to MLSB
               int MLSB = M&1; 
               //Assigning Least significant bit of P to PLSB
               int PLSB = P&1; 

               //printing LSB values
               printf("\nValue in MLSB : %d and Value in PLSB : %d",MLSB,PLSB); 

               //Comparing MLSB and PLSB
               if(MLSB != PLSB) { 
                   printf("\nLeast significant bits are not equal"); 
               }
               else printf("\nLeast significant bits are equal"); 


            }
```

Output :

Least significant bits are for M : 1 and for P : 1
Least significant bits are not equal
Value in MLSB : 1 and Value in PLSB : 1
Least significant bits are equal

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this

```
if(M&1 != P&1) {
```

into

```
if((M&1) != (P&1)) {
```

and then check the precedence of operators, e.g. here https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 2):

please check [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

`if(M&1 != P&1)`

this will comapare (1 != P), which returns true. add brackets around bitwise operation.